# unable to import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webclient

i am trying to create a springboot application but i am not very sure why my import statements are generating these errors in the terminal when i try to compile my App.java

```
Application.java:4: error: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure does not exist
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
                                             ^
Application.java:5: error: package org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client does not exist
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
                                                       ^
```

here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>cs</groupId>
    <artifactId>openshift-traefik-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>openshift-traefik-test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

i am using visual studio code to code this java project

Comment: How are you compiling? Use plain `javac` or, as you should, Maven?